# Themes for Evolution

Tags: 18.04, evolution

I strongly prefer a dark theme, but I can't seem to find any current documentation on how to change the theme in Evolution?

Does anyone have any tips?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Evolution doesn't have its own themes. Selecting a dark GTK+ 3.0 theme should cover most of the UI, but mail and composer views may not follow as they are web views.

Answer (score 5):

Evolution doesn't have a theme section it self, **but with `gtk+ ≥ 3.12` you can set a theme on a specific app like evolution.**

you can run a specific app with a specific theme with the command `GTK_THEME=<theme-name> <application>`  , for example, you can enter `GTK_THEME=Yaru-dark evolution` in terminal to run evolution with `yaru dark` theme.

**And, If you want to make that theme permanent for a program,**

you should go to `/usr/share/applications` and find and copy the `.desktop` file of the application, mine was `org.gnome.Evolution.desktop` in this case.
then, paste it in `~/.local/share/applications` and open it with a text editor,

then, find every line starting with `Exec=`, right after the `=` add `env GTK_THEME=<theme-name>` and put a space after it so the rest of the line will be in front of it, for example: `Exec=env GTK_THEME=Yaru-Dark evolution -c current`

then save the file and enjoy :)

(the reason we didn't edit the file in the original directory is that if the application got got updated, It won't get overwritten)

Comment: by the way, I really like `Arc-Dark` and `Arc-Darker` themes on evolution, although you should install them first

Comment: this doesn't seem to work in fedora 35, i didn't copy to local just sudo nano the desktop file in place for all users

Answer (score 0):

remember to use a theme installed on your computer. otherwise worked perfectly ty. my theme
env GTK_THEME=Mint-Y-Dark evolution -c current